# Dispaly an array of objects from an API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display an array of information on my page but I'm stuck on how I should do it.

I believe that the problem is in how I'm trying to render it but I have already done so many tries that I run out of ideas.

In the console, I´m having success on the request and I receive the array, but I can't figure out how to display it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const MyLocations = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("");
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState("");
  console.log(endDate);
  console.log(startDate);
  const tokenAtual = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
  const [getLocations, setLocations] = useState([]);



  const handleList = () => {
    
    var axios = require("axios");
    var data = '{\r\n  "end": "2022-07-01",\r\n  "start": "2022-01-01"\r\n}';

    var config = {
      method: "post",
      url: "https://api.secureme.pt/api/v1/position/history",
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          tokenAtual,
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
      },
      data: data,
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);
          setLocations(response.data);
          return
            <div>
              <h1>getLocations.map(response.data.location.latitide)</h1>
              <h1>getLocations.map(response.data.location.longitude)</h1>
            </div>
        
  })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });


  }

    return (
        <div>
          <title>My Locations</title>

          <input
          type="button"
          className="btn-pastLocals"
          onClick={handleList}
          value={"See Past Locations"}
        />
          <input
            type="date"
            className="start-date"
            placeholder="Start Date"
            value={startDate}
            onChange={(e) => setStartDate(e.target.value)}/>

          <input
            type="date"
            className="end-date"
            placeholder="End Date"
            value={endDate}
            onChange={(e) => setEndDate(e.target.value)}/>
          
        </div>
      );
}

export default MyLocations;
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank you..!!

Comment: What do you expect the `return <div><h1> etc...` in the `axios(config).then` function to do? Because whatever is returned is currently not being used at all.

Comment: I'm trying to render it...

Comment: You can't render anything inside the `axios(config).then` function. What you need to do is to conditionally add the html elements to the existing `return (<div><title> etc...` via the getLocations state.

Comment: So I need to create a function that will call getLocation, return it to html code and the call it inside the axios?

Comment: Don't return anything from the Axios callback. Save the information in `state`, then add it to the return value of the component (e.g. after your inputs). The logic here is that initially, when the component is first rendered, the state will be empty, so it won't be present in the returned HTML. The axios callback will be fired after some time and change the state of your component, which will force it to re-render, this time with the object taken from its state.

Comment: @DarioSantos You should probably change the name from `getLocation` to `location`, since you are supposed to treat it sort of like it's a variable (that can only be indirectly changed through the setLocations function) rather than like it's a function. You don't "call" a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work if the the locations array has this structure

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const MyLocations = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("");
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState("");
  console.log(endDate);
  console.log(startDate);
  const tokenAtual = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
  const [getLocations, setLocations] = useState([]);



  const handleList = () => {
    
    var axios = require("axios");
    var data = '{\r\n  "end": "2022-07-01",\r\n  "start": "2022-01-01"\r\n}';

    var config = {
      method: "post",
      url: "https://api.secureme.pt/api/v1/position/history",
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          tokenAtual,
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
      },
      data: data,
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);
          setLocations(response.data);
  })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });


  }

    return (
        <div>
          <title>My Locations</title>
          {locations.map((location) => {
             return (
             <>
              <h1>
                {location.data.location.latitude}
              </h1>
              <h1>
                {location.data.location.latitude}
              </h1>
             </>
             )
          })}
          <input
          type="button"
          className="btn-pastLocals"
          onClick={handleList}
          value={"See Past Locations"}
        />
          <input
            type="date"
            className="start-date"
            placeholder="Start Date"
            value={startDate}
            onChange={(e) => setStartDate(e.target.value)}/>

          <input
            type="date"
            className="end-date"
            placeholder="End Date"
            value={endDate}
            onChange={(e) => setEndDate(e.target.value)}/>
          
        </div>
      );
}

export default MyLocations;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to study the react documentation and learn how it works.

Secondly, here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
return (
  <div>
    <title>My Locations</title>

    {
      getLocations.map(
        location => (
          <div>
            <h1>
              {location.data.location.latitude}
            </h1>
            <h1>
              {location.data.location.latitude}
            </h1>
          </div>
        )
      )
    }

etc...
```

Comment: It's a good answer, but it's worth adding that returning anything from a functional component in an async callback is a terrible practice.

Comment: I did write that you can't render anything inside an axios call, in the comments to the question. But yeah, returning anything from an axios call is of course a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, the point is that I'm learning react and this is also a project to my classes. With no experience this can become a "little" overwhelming.